# Perform Action in MQTT Subscriber

Tags: mqtt, subscribe

This mqtt subscriber code works fine. I can easily subscribe to messages which are published at broker.hivemq.com with respective topic.

```
public class AccelerometerSubscriber  implements MqttCallback,  
IMqttActionListener {

public static void main(String[] args)  throws MqttException  {
int QUALITY_OF_SERVICE = 2;
MqttClient client=new MqttClient("tcp://broker.hivemq.com:1883", 
MqttClient.generateClientId());
client.setCallback( new SimpleMqttCallBack() );
client.connect();
System.out.println("Subscribing ....");
client.subscribe("MQTT Examples");    }

System.out.println("some action"); //------------right here--------------

public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

System.out.println("Connection to MQTT broker lost!");  }


public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {

  System.out.println("Message received:\n\t"+ new String(mqttMessage.getPayload()) );

}   

 public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

  // not used in this example

}}
```

Now I want to perform action only when a message is received. I'm unable to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a class (AccelerometerSubscriber) that implements the interface `MqttCallback`, use an instance of it instead of doing  `client.setCallback( new SimpleMqttCallBack() );`

```
public class AccelerometerSubscriber implements MqttCallback, IMqttActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MqttException {
        AccelerometerSubscriber as = new AccelerometerSubscriber();
        int QUALITY_OF_SERVICE = 2;
        MqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://broker.hivemq.com:1883", MqttClient.generateClientId());
        client.setCallback(as);
        client.connect();
        System.out.println("Subscribing ....");
        client.subscribe("MQTT Examples");
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println("Connection to MQTT broker lost!");
    }
    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
        //message is received is here!!!
        System.out.println("Message received:\n\t" + new String(mqttMessage.getPayload()));
    }
    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
        System.out.println("deliveryComplete");
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(IMqttToken arg0, Throwable arg1) {
        System.out.println("onFailure");
    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken arg0) {
        System.out.println("onSuccess");
    }
}
```